# How to get result after flatMap and throw a new Observer with result?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, observers, flatmap

I have the following Observer method:

```
public __init__(httpResponse: HttpResponse<any>): Observable<any> {
    return this.initializeCredentials(httpResponse.headers, httpResponse.body['result']).flatMap((res) => {
      return this.initializePeriod(res);
    });
```

Where `initializeCredentials()` returns Observer:

```
private initializeCredentials(headers: HttpHeaders, body: any): Observable <any> {
   return Observable.of({'a' :1});
}
```

And `initializePeriod()` returns Observer:

```
private initializePeriod(profile: any): Observable<Period> {
   return return Observable.of({'b' :2});
 }
```

How to get result after second Observer: `return this.initializePeriod(res);` and throw out result farther to method `__init__()`?

**Notice:** It is important to pass result from first Observer to second `this.initializePeriod()`.

In result I need to subsrube on `__init__()` and get both result from Observerbes:

```
this.__init__().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: So you want to `this.initializeCredentials` to call `this.initializePeriod` and then return both results from `__init__()`? Or if you want to return only the second result I don't understand where's the problem?

Comment: Yes, I want return both results, but second does not return Observer back to __init_())

Comment: Isn't it the other way around right now? You only get result from the second Observable `this.initializeCredentials` and not the first one?

Comment: I need to get result after second Observer immidiatly the call custom function and return right here a new Observer back

Comment: Here `return this.initializePeriod(res);` to get result and return ``Observer.of(result)`; back to `__init__();`

Comment: I tried this inside: ` return this.initializePeriod(input).map((x) => 
        {
          alert(x);  return Observer.of(x);
        });` It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rxjs5 there's a result selector function for flatMap

```
public __init__(httpResponse: HttpResponse<any>): Observable<any> {
    return this.initializeCredentials(httpResponse.headers, httpResponse.body['result']).flatMap((res) => {
      return this.initializePeriod(res);
    },
(firstRes,secondRes)=>{
return {firstRes,secondRes}
}
);
```